# Por que se coloca -1 en este caso

Tags: javascript

No entiendo porque va !== -1, sin eso el codigo no me funciona pero con eso si, y el profesor no me explico porque iba, me pueden explicar por favor? Gracias

```
let colores = ["azul","amarillo","rojo","verde","rosa"]
let color = prompt("Escribe un color");

if(colores.indexOf(color) !== -1){
    console.log(`El color ${color} esta en el array`)
} else {
    console.log(`El color ${color} NO esta en el array`)
}
```

Comment: Una búsqueda en Google del método [**`indexOf`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf) rápido nos aclara que el -1 es para cuando el *elemento no esta presente*

Comment: Y lo que evalúa en la condición es *si el  resultado del `indexOf` es distinto de -1 entonces el elemento si esta en el array*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La funcion 'indexOf()' devulve un numero, devuelve -1 si no encuentra nada (valor por defecto siempre), y en caso de encontrar lo que se pides por teclado te retorna la posicion en el array donde se encuentra, por ejemplo si buscas el color rojo, en tu ejemplo, te retornara 2.

En la condicion 'if (colores.indexOf(color) !== -1)' lo que estas dicion es que si al hacer la busqueda, si el retorno de la funcion es distinto de -1, como en el ejemplo anterior, si buscas el color rojo te devuelve 2, 2 es distinto de -1, por lo tanto cumple la condicion, en el caso contrario si no encuentra el color, por ejemplo el color lima, no existe en el array por lo que la funcion 'indexOf()' te retornara -1, la condicion no se cumple ya que no es distinto de -1 y salta al 'else'.

```js
let colores = ["azul", "amarillo", "rojo", "verde", "rosa"]
let color = 'rojo';

// el color 'rojo' ocupa la posicion 2 en el array, 'indexOf()' devuelve un valor de 2, al ser distinto de -1, como pone en la condicion, se cumple dicha condicion, el color si existe en el array
if (colores.indexOf(color) !== -1) {
  console.log(`El color ${color} esta en el array`)
} else {
  console.log(`El color ${color} NO esta en el array`)
}

let color2 = 'lima'; // creo otra variable.

// el color 'lima' no existe en el array, por lo que la funcion 'indexOf()' no encontrara dicho valor, por lo que devolvera -1, el color no existe en el array.
if (colores.indexOf(color2) !== -1) {
  console.log(`El color ${color2} esta en el array`)
} else {
  console.log(`El color ${color2} NO esta en el array`)
}
```

Espero haberme explicado lo mejor posible, o al menos mejor que en la anterior vez, disculpa y un saludo.

Comment: Recomendaria que le explicaras mejor al usuario lo que intentas decir, la respuesta carece de calidad y tampoco se entiende mucho.

Comment: He cambiado mi respuesta y he intentado explicarme de nuevo de una manera mas clara.

Comment: mejor edita la respuesta en lugar de publicar otra

Comment: No estaba muy seguro de como hacerlo, pido disculpas, lo tendre en cuenta en el futuro. Ya lo he cambiado, espero que le ayude al usuario.